# Using TF Estimator with TFRecord generator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to create a simple NN that reads in a folder of tfrecords. Each record has a 1024-value 'mean_rgb' vector, and a category label. I am trying to create a simple feed-forward NN that learns the categories based on this feature vector.

```
def generate(dir, shuffle, batch_size):
    def parse(serialized):
        features = {
            'mean_rgb': tf.FixedLenFeature([1024], tf.float32),
            'category': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
        parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized, features=features)
        vrv = parsed_example['mean_rgb']
        label = parsed_example['category']
        d = dict(zip(['mean_rgb'], [vrv])), label
        return d

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(dir).repeat(1)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse)
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(8000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next = iterator.get_next()
    print(next)
    return next

def batch_generator(dir, shuffle=False, batch_size=64):
    sess = K.get_session()
    while True:
        yield sess.run(generate(dir, shuffle, batch_size))

num_classes = 29
batch_size = 64

yt8m_train = [os.path.join(yt8m_dir_train, x) for x in read_all_file_names(yt8m_dir_train) if '.tfrecord' in x]

yt8m_test = [os.path.join(yt8m_dir_test, x) for x in read_all_file_names(yt8m_dir_test) if '.tfrecord' in x]

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in ['mean_rgb']]

#batch_generator(yt8m_test).__next__()

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[1024, 1024],
    n_classes=num_classes,
    model_dir=model_dir)

classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda: generate(yt8m_train, True, batch_size))
```

However, I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a
>   tensor with 65536 values, but the requested shape has 64

I am not sure why it sees the input as a 64x1024=65536 vector instead of a (64, 1024) vector. When I print the next item in the generator, I get

```
({'mean_rgb': <tf.Tensor: id=23, shape=(64, 1024), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.9243997 ,  0.28990048, -0.4130672 , ..., -0.096692  ,
         0.27225342,  0.13346168],
       [ 0.5853526 ,  0.67050666, -0.24683481, ..., -0.6999033 ,
        -0.4100128 , -0.00349384],
       [ 0.49572858,  0.5231492 , -0.53445834, ...,  0.0449002 ,
         0.10582132, -0.37333965],
       ...,
       [ 0.5776026 , -0.07128889, -0.61762846, ...,  0.22194198,
         0.61441416, -0.27355513],
       [-0.01848815,  0.20132884,  1.1023484 , ...,  0.06496283,
         0.29560333,  0.09157721],
       [-0.25877073, -1.9552246 ,  0.10309827, ...,  0.22032814,
        -0.6812989 , -0.23649289]], dtype=float32)>}
```

which has the correct (64, 1024) shape

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the issue was that `feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in ['mean_rgb']]` assumes that the column is a scalar - when actually it is a 1024 vector. I had to add `shape=1024` to the numeric_column call. Also had to remove existing checkpoint saved model.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is at how the features_columns works, for example, I had a similar problem and I solved by doing a reshape here is part of my code that will help you understand:

defining the features_column:

```
feature_columns = {
        'images': tf.feature_column.numeric_column('images', self.shape),
    }
```

then to create the input for the model:

```
        with tf.name_scope('input'):
            feature_columns = list(self._features_columns().values())
            input_layer = tf.feature_column.input_layer(
                features=features, feature_columns=feature_columns)

            input_layer = tf.reshape(
                input_layer,
                shape=(-1, self.parameters.size, self.parameters.size,
                       self.parameters.channels))
```

if pay attention to the last part I had to reshape the tensor, the -1 is to let Tensorflow figure out the batch size